# Getting the other values in a record if given the ID in Isar database using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-isar

I'm using the Isar database in a Flutter application, but I'm unable access the properties of a stored object. I'm only able to retrieve an Instance of the Object.

This is my collection:

```
@Collection()
 class User{
 Id? id;
 late String name;
 late String email;
 
 @Index()
 late String phone;
}
```

This is how I'm trying to access the record from the login page:

final users = widget.isar.users.where()
.phoneEqualTo(phone)
.findAll();

> In this case **users** is returned as [Instance of 'User']

I want to access the name of the record corresponding to the phone number. How would I go about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must be trying to print the result. 

You are correct, your method is working as expected, you can loop over the items in `users` and access props like ```users[0].phone ```

Comment: @YogeshDubey if I wanted to assign the name of the record that I access to a variable userName, what would the statement be? I'm a little confused by the access methods given by Isar.

Comment: It would be straight  ```final  userName = users[index].name```

Answer (score 0):

@Sharvan Kumaran Simply get the initial element and convert it into a User object.

```
final users = widget.isar.users.where().phoneEqualTo(phone).findAll();

if (users.isNotEmpty) {
  User user = users.first;
  String name = user.name;
  String email = user.email;
}
```